# How to convert a vector of vectors to a Mat matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert a `vector of vectors` (kind of 2D array) to a `Mat` matrix. Here below is my code:

```
template<class T>
void vec2Mat(vector<vector<T>> const &myVec, Mat &myMat)
{
    int H = myVec.size();
    int W = myVec[0].size();
    for(int i=0; i<H; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<W; j++)
        {
            myMat.at<T>(i,j) = myVec[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

This function cannot be compiled because of the `Error: Assertion failed (data) in cv::Mat::at`. Anyone can help me to correct my code?

Except looping the individual elements as above, are there any more convenient (and efficient) methods to do the conversion?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. You just have to pay attention, that dimensions and types match. For example, you have your "array" as something like `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> myVec = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}`, then you need to set up the matrix as `cv::Mat myMat = cv::Mat(2, 3, CV_8UC1)`. You see: two rows = two entries in your "outer vector", three columns = three elements per "inner vector", `uint8_t` = `CV_8UC1`. I guess, at least one of these requirements failed in the example you tested (but unfortunately not showed here).

Comment: Have you initialized `myMat ` to be of the same size and type as as `myVec `?

Comment: Per-pixel operations are very slow and should be considered a last resort. Both `cv::Mat` and `std::vector` have a `data()` member for direct buffer access, and there's also `std::copy()` for more generic STL container copying. Also, `cv::Mat` has a constructor that accepts a buffer pointer to wrap an existing buffer.